# Php неопределенное свойство

Tags: php

Сервер, error log **сыпет** ошибками относительно компонента sppagebuilder, разработчик на вопросы не отвечает, так как с php на ВЫ ищу помощи здесь. Как побороть эти ошибки?

Кусок лога,вернее два:

```
[error] 17916#17916: *12766 FastCGI sent in stderr: "PHP message: PHP Notice:  Undefined property: stdClass::$section_height_option in /home/xxxxx/web/mysite.com/public_html/components/com_sppagebuilder/layouts/row/css.php on line 32PHP
 PHP Notice:  Uninitialized string offset: 11 in /home/xxxxx/web/mysite.com/public_html/components/com_sppagebuilder/helpers/css-parser.php on line 110PHP
```

И:

```
[error] 17916#17916: *12766 FastCGI sent in stderr: "Uninitialized string offset: 48 in /home/xxxxx/web/mysite.com/public_html/components/com_sppagebuilder/helpers/css-parser.php on line 110PHP
PHP Notice:  Uninitialized string offset: 58 in /home/xxxxx/web/mysite.com/public_html/components/com_sppagebuilder/helpers/css-parser.php on line 110PHP
```

Так же два **фрагмента** кода:1-css.php.2-css-parser.php

```
$row_styles = '';
$style ='';
$style_sm ='';
$style_xs ='';

if(isset($options->section_height)){
    if(is_object($options->section_height)){
        if(isset($options->section_height->md) && $options->section_height->md){
            if($options->section_height_option=='height'){
                $style .= 'height:'.$options->section_height->md.'px;';
            }
        }

        if (isset($options->section_height->sm) && $options->section_height->sm){
            if($options->section_height_option=='height'){
                $style_sm .= 'height:'.$options->section_height->sm.'px;';
            }
        }

        if (isset($options->section_height->xs) && $options->section_height->xs){
            if($options->section_height_option=='height'){
                $style_xs .= 'height:'.$options->section_height->xs.'px;';
            }
        }
    } else {
        if ($options->section_height) {
            if($options->section_height_option=='height'){
                $style .= 'height:'.$options->section_height.'px;';
            }
        }
    }
}
```

2-css-parser.php

```
$css = preg_replace('/\/\*.*\*\//Us', '', $css);
while(preg_match('/^\s*(\@(media|import|local)([^\{\}]+)(\{)|([^\{\}]+)(\{)|([^\{\}]*)(\}))/Usi', $css, $match)) {
  if(isset($match[8]) && ($match[8] == '}')) {
    if($section !== false) {
      $code = trim($match[7]);
      $idx = 0;
      $inQuote = false;
      $property = false;
      $codeLen = strlen($code);
      $parenthesis = array();
      while($idx < $codeLen) {

        if($code == null){
            break;
        }
        $c = $code{$idx};
        $idx++;
        if($inQuote !== false) {
          if($inQuote === $c) {
            $inQuote = false;
          }
        } elseif(($inQuote === false) && ($c == '(')) {
          array_push($parenthesis, '(');
        } elseif(($inQuote === false) && ($c == ')')) {
          array_pop($parenthesis);
        } elseif(($c == '\'') || ($c == '"')) {
          $inQuote = $c;
        } elseif(($property === false) && ($c == ':')) {
          $property = trim(substr($code, 0, $idx - 1));
          if(preg_match('/^(.*)\[([0-9]*)\]$/Us', $property, $propMatch)) {
            $property = $propMatch[1].'['.static::$propCounter.']';
            static::$propCounter += 1;
          }
          $code = substr($code, $idx);
          $idx = 0;
        } elseif((count((array) $parenthesis) == 0) && ($c == ';')) {
          $value = trim(substr($code, 0, $idx - 1));
          $code = substr($code, $idx);
          $idx = 0;
          $this->AddProperty($currentMedia, $section, $property, $value);
          $property = false;
        }
```

для css.php 32 строка начинается с `if($options->section_height_option=='height')`

для css-parser.php 110строка начинается с `$c = $code{$idx};`(Решение найдено)

Остается вопрос по  css.php,свежий лог

```
09:28:50 [error] 964#964: *414 FastCGI sent in stderr: "PHP message: PHP Notice:  Undefined property: stdClass::$section_height_option in /home/xxxxx/web/mysite.com/public_html/components/com_sppagebuilder/layouts/row/css.php on line 32PHP message: PHP Notice:  Undefined property: stdClass::$section_height_option in /home/xxxxx/web/mysite.com/public_html/components/com_sppagebuilder/layouts/row/css.php on line 32PHP message: PHP Warning:  "continue" targeting switch is equivalent to "break". Did you mean to use "continue 2"? in /home/xxxxx/web/mysite.com/public_html/plugins/system/helixultimate/core/classes/Minifier.php on line 226" while reading response header from upstream, client: 54.37.73.108, server: mysite.com, request: "GET / HTTP/2.0", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/run/php/php7.3-fpm-mysite.com.sock:", host: "mysite.com"
```

Как победить?

Comment: День добрый. Приложите код и ошибку текстом, а не скриншотами.

Comment: Спасибо,подправил

Comment: `strlen` замените на `mb_strlen` где найдете

Comment: Спасибо teran,замена не помогает,лог на месте

Comment: $c = $code{$idx};менял на скобки [],безрезультатно..

Comment: найдено решение для css-parser.php,$c = $code{$idx};заменой на $c = isset($code{$idx}) ? $code{$idx} : '';